# Confusion about microstate probabilities

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

So I know we have the Gibbs Entropy Formula
$$S=k\sum_i p_i \ln p_i$$
And I've seen the probabilities for the microstates be said to be the Boltzmann probabilities
$$p_i\propto e^{-\frac{E_i}{kT}}$$
But I've also seen that to obtain Boltzmann's entropy formula you assume all states have the same probability so, if $\Omega$ is the number of accessible microstates then we have
$$S=k \ln \Omega$$
So either the probability for all microstates is the same, it is proportional to the Boltzmann Factor, or I am missing a big chunk of information.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The Boltzmann's entropy formula is valid in the microcanical ensemble, where the number of particles $N$, the volume $V$ and the energy $E$ are fixed. In this case we postulate that all microstates are equally probable, and define $\Omega$ as the number of microstates that have an energy comprised between $E$ and $E + \Delta$, where $\Delta \ll E$.

If we are in the canonical ensemble, in which $N$, $V$ and temperature $T$ are fixed, things are a bit different. In particular, the Boltzmann relation for $S$ is not valid, as the entropy is now given by

$$
S = -\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial T} \right)_{N,V}
$$

where $F$ is the Helmholtz free energy. In this ensemble, the probability of a microstate, as you wrote, is proportional to the Boltzmann factor:

$$
p_i\propto e^{-\frac{E_i}{kT}}
$$